Alternate sum of Chebyshev polynomials
The problem is

For all integer $n\ge1$,
\begin{align}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n-1}}\left(\frac12+\sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{k} T_k(x)\right)&=\prod _{j=0}^{n-1} \left(x-\cos \left(\frac{\pi  (2 j+1)}{2 n+1}\right)\right)\\&=\pm2^{-n}\sqrt{\frac{T_{2n+1}(x)+1}{x+1}}\end{align}

My attempt:
They are monic polynomials of same degree, I only need verify they have same roots.
The roots of right side are $x=\cos\frac{(2j+1)π}{2n+1}\;,j=0,1,⋯,n-1$.
So I need prove
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\cos\left(k\frac{(2j+1)π}{2n+1}\right)=\frac12\quad,j=0,1,⋯,n-1$$

$x=\cos\frac{(2j+1)π}{2n+1}\;,j=0,1,⋯,n-1$ are roots of $T_{2n+1}(x)=-1$.
Since $\cos\frac{(2j+1)π}{2n+1}$ are extrema of $T_{2n+1}(x)$, they are roots of its derivative:
$$T_{2n+1}'(x)=2^{2n}(2n+1)\prod _{j=0}^{n-1} \left(x-\cos \left(\frac{\pi  (2 j+1)}{2 n+1}\right)\right)\prod _{j=0}^{n-1} \left(x+\cos \left(\frac{\pi  (2 j+1)}{2 n+1}\right)\right)$$

If $x=\cos\theta,$ then the left side is, without the sign, $$\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=-n}^n(-1)^k\cos k\theta=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=-n}^n (-1)^ke^{ik\theta}.$$ This is a geometric series with common term $-e^{i\theta}.$

@ThomasAndrews the sum doesn't contain $k=0$

The left side includes $\frac12,$ which is the case $k=0.$ @hbghlyj

I certainly didn't write out all the steps, but the equalities are true.

Replacing $j$ with $n-j$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\cos\left(k\frac{(2(n-j)+1)π}{2n+1}\right)=\frac12\quad,j=1,⋯,n$$
Since $k\frac{(2(n-j)+1)π}{2n+1}=k\pi-k\frac{2jπ}{2n+1}$, it becomes
$$\sum_{k=1}^n-\cos\left(k\frac{2jπ}{2n+1}\right)=\frac12\quad,j=1,⋯,n$$
Writing $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$,
$$-\sum_{k=1}^n\exp\left(ik\frac{2jπ}{2n+1}\right)-\sum_{k=-n}^{-1}\exp\left(ik\frac{2jπ}{2n+1}\right)=1\quad,j=1,⋯,n$$
Writing $1=\exp\left(i0\frac{2jπ}{2n+1}\right)$, it becomes
$$\sum_{k=-n}^n\exp\left(ik\frac{2jπ}{2n+1}\right)=0\quad,j=1,⋯,n$$
This is a geometric series with common ratio $\exp(i\frac{2jπ}{2n+1})\ne1$.
$$\sum_{k=-n}^n\exp\left(ik\frac{2jπ}{2n+1}\right)=\frac{\exp\left(i(n+1)\frac{2jπ}{2n+1}\right)-\exp\left(-in\frac{2jπ}{2n+1}\right)}{\exp(i\frac{2jπ}{2n+1})-1}=0$$

It's always dangerous to use $i$ as an index when dealing with trig functions, because of the likelihood you will want to write $e^{iy},$ thus making $i$ ambiguous.

@ThomasAndrews Thanks, I use $\mathrm{i}$ for imaginary unit, and $i$ for index

Not enough visual difference. Use $j$ for the index, not $i.$

@ThomasAndrews Ok, I changed to $j$
